# While loop Does not finish even when statement goes false

Tags: c#, while-loop, serial-port

I'm writing a WinForm application to control an encoder engine via serial port. The protocol is quite simple, I send the 1st command to ask engine moving, and the 2nd command to confirm it's been in new position, and so on for other places. Here is my code for this:

```
string dataRead ="";
serialPort1.Write("P.1=2950\r\n"); //Location register (2950)
serialPort1.Write("^.1\r\n"); //Moving command

while (dataRead.Contains("Px.1=2950") == false)
{
   serialPort1.Write("?96.1\r\n"); //Ask for current location
   respond3 = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
   dataRead = string.Concat(dataRead, respond3);

}
//Keep moving to 710 after stop at 2950
serialPort1.Write("P.1=710\r\n"); //Location register (710)
serialPort1.Write("^.1\r\n"); //Moving command
```

The problem is, when I debug my app, it's stuck in the while-loop. But if I break all, and then continue again, it will pass. The `respond3` is used to get output from the engine. Whenever it gets a correct respond, the while-loop will finish.

Comment: does readExisting method reads a new element everytime ?

Comment: yes, I put a break point and check the value of respond3,  it records all messages including the thing I'm waiting for. But it does not exit a while loop until I pause at break point and continue run again.

Comment: Try adding something like thread.sleep after you send the data since it needs some time to respond

Comment: Your code looks fine. I think this boils down to whether or not `serialPort1.ReadExisting()` returns a string containing `"?96.1\r\n"`. How are we meant to test that?

Comment: you are right. Here this what I received when put break point after serialPort1.ReadExisting(): "?96.1\r\n?96.1\r\n?96.1\r\n?96.1\r\nPx.1=2950\r\n". You can see it replied many times before return a correct position (Px.1=2950). But I don't know why while-loop doesn't finish.

Comment: `ReadExisting` doesn't guarantee that you get a complete message. Try printing out to the debug console what you read, I'm guessing you'll see that its partial messages. The reason it works when you pause is that the buffer has time to fill up and get the message with the complete data in it. I'm guessing messages have a delimiter (\r\n), you should add data to a buffer until you get the delimiter then check if the buffer contains that message.

Comment: there is no problem with loop. sure that ReadExisting does not return correct value at all.

Comment: It returns correct value actually. Even at some points it may fail to receive, but the asking command will be sent repeatedly until getting the correct message. As Ron Beyer mentioned, It may due to there's no time to update. I'll try to insert a wait point, hope it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is how [`ReadExisting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting(v=vs.110).aspx) works. The important part is:

> Reads all **immediately available** bytes, based on the encoding, in both the stream and the input buffer of the SerialPort object.

Emphasis mine.

When you're debugging, the IO port has more time to read data, so you'll get a long string in your input like so:

> `"?96.1\r\n?96.1\r\n?96.1\r\n?96.1\r\nPx.1=2950\r\n"`

However, when you're not debugging the code runs faster, and you will get: `"?"` followed by `"9"` etc.

As such the *immediately available* string will never match the string `"Px.1=2950"` and your loop will never stop.

What you probably want to use, given the newline delimited string you are using, is the [`ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting(v=vs.110).aspx) method.